# Why should $\lim_{V\to\infty} \frac{1}{V} \ln Q(z, V, T)$ have a finite limit?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

In the book *Intro. Statistical Physics* by K.Huang, on page 174, it is given that

> In the thermodynamic limit $V \rightarrow \infty,$ we expect that:
> $$
> \frac{1}{V} \ln Q(z, V, T) \underset{V \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \text { Finite limit. }
> $$
> where Q is the grand canonical partition function.

This is *expected* but is there any mathematical or physical reason and/or evidence/explanation for why this is/should be the case?

Comment: The existence of the thermodynamic limit has been rigorously proved in great generality since the 1960s. One standard early reference is Ruelle's [famous monograph](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4090) (see chapters 2 and 3 for the cases of lattice, respectively, continuum systems, both classical and quantum).

Answer (score 2):

There is no mathematical proof just because, in general, it is not true that the limit exists or it is finite. Of course, we would expect a finite limit as a precondition for a thermodynamic interpretation of the statistical mechanics formula.

The right question is not about the reason for a finite limit, but to ask the question *do we have a good characterization of the Hamiltonians which ensure the existence of thermodynamic limit*?

Indeed, a set of sufficient conditions for the existence of the thermodynamic limit, ensuring at the same time the correct properties of convexity of the resulting fundamental equation, is known for different classes of systems. For an overview see [this paper.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7172)

Comment: Of course, the reference given by @YvanVelenik in his comment is a cornerstone for this topic.

Comment: Your linking reference is studying how big the system is big enough to render  thermodynamic relation from statistic formulation, e.g. the equipartition of energy. It is not  stduying the "existence" of thermal dynamical limit. Your statement is misleading.

Comment: @ytlu I repeat that the two things are strongly connected.  In order to exist the limit of $\frac{\ln Q}{V}$ for $V \rightarrow \infty$ it is necessary that $\ln Q$ would scale like $V$. Wouldn't you agree? Do you think the correct scaling does not depend on the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Certain not on the Hamiltonian, but depend on how big the system is. And I repeat, the concern of the paper is how good the result is, NOT the existence of the limit.

Comment: @ytlu It is the same thing. Try to evaluate the partition function of a system interacting with a long-range force and you'll realize it. I have the impression that you ignore everything about the thermodynamic limit. Maybe after you'll read Ruelle's book cited by Velenik, we can resume this discussion.

Comment: For long range interaction, the problem is not on the partition function. But it needs a different structure of thermodynamics. This problem is not well described by the tranditional thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

In grand canonical ensemble, the partition function $Q$ and the grand potential has relation
$$
\Phi = -K T \ln Q.
$$

The grand potential (also known as Landau free energy) in thermodynamics can be derived using Legendre transformation from internal energy $U(N,V, S)$, where $S$ is the entropy:

The Helmholtz free energy
$$
F = F - TS; \text{  and  } F = F(N, V, T).
$$

Then, the grand potential:
$$
\Phi = F - N\mu; \text{  and  } \Phi = \Phi(\mu, V, T).
$$

The grand potential is an extended quantity, as well the volume $V$, but $T$ and $\mu$ are intensive quantity. The form of grand potential:

$$
\Phi = P V.
$$

Thus,
$$
\lim_{\text{thermal-limit}} \frac{\ln Q(\mu,V, T)}{V} = -\frac{P}{KT}.
$$

$P$ and $T$ are intensity variables will not change as the system becomes larger.

Comment: $P$ is *defined* for every $V$ by $k_BT\frac{\ln Q}{V}$. One should **prove** that it is an intensive quantity. It cannot be assumed.

Comment: It is not the definition for P. The grand potential is equal to $PV$ is a thermodynamic relation. P is exactly the pressure. The only hypothesis is $\Phi  = -KT\ln Q$. This is the bridge from statistics to thermodynamics.The test equations are relations of thermodynamics. Most of them are Maxwell relations.

Comment: Check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_potential. The relations $\Phi = PV$ is a pure thermodynamic relation: grand potential = pressure $\times$ volume.

Comment: No problem with the Grand_potential, although its name in thermodynamic is different. However, the problem is the connection with the partition function. Every relation between partition functions and thermodynamic potentials is not unconditionally consistent with thermodynamics. It happens that in general, for interacting finite systems, the log of partition functions does not have all the properties of the corresponding thermodynamic potential. In particular, it does not scale as $V$, due to finite-size effects. The correct scaling is restored only by taking the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: In this post, it is a problem about the limit $V \to \infty$. We are not discussing the small system. In the previous comment, you are questioned me about the $P$ as if it is a new defined term from the statistics.  Now, your are circling the focus.

Comment: It is exactly the same problem. The thermodynamic limit is necessary precisely to eliminate every finite-size effect on the statistically defined thermodynamic quantities. If you start with $\ln Q$, how can you prove it scales like $V$? By proof, of course, I do not mean just to state it. Without a proof, it is not me who is circling the focus.

Comment: The $\Phi = -KT \ln Q$ is a well established relation rooted from the Boltzmann hypothesis, and $\Phi=PV$ is well-known thermal dynamical relation. The above two relations, which one is your concern?

Comment: I have no concern. I am trying to bring your attention on the fact that what you call the Boltzmann hypothesis, i.e. the connection between partition function and thermodynamics is correct only at the thermodynamic limit. If you think that things are that simple why people should look for the thermodynamic limit? Why computer simulations should bother about finite-size effects?

Comment: I know that it is only good for the limit of large system, a well-known base of doing statistics. e.g. $\ln n! = n \ln n - n$, central limit, etc. As for how fast it converges to the limit value, that is another problem. You had opened this problem saying that "if the limit exists or not". As long as I didn't encounter a system of divergent limit, I won't start to seriously consider it. If you like to talk about how accaurae is the finit system, please open another post.